# How to filter the modified date column to get documents today 8 am to 10 am

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, sharepoint-server

[image]How to filter the modified date column, I am creating a view based on I want to show documents which are uploaded by today only but from morning 8 am to 9am .

Answer (score 1):

We can't put calculation formulas in filter text so something like `Today()+8` etc will not work.

Two work arounds

1. Use CSR/JSLinks to hide rows which don't fall in that time period.
2. Use query string filtering. I.e. calculate the date range and sent it via query string ( ex: on link click which open the view page)

Comment: i can not get your point, i just creating view that shows the documents uploaded today morning from 8 to 10 am. how can i do this?

Comment: You can't create such views using out of the box filtering feature.

Comment: so how i use ur  above said methods , can u give some links , i am not aware that how to create query  string filtering  and  js links

Comment: I second the JSLink. It's a very powerful feature of SharePoint that allows you to manipulate the way a webpart/content type looks through HTML/CSS and can traverse through and manipulate each item that the view returns. It allows you to use the fields in that item so you can filter. Very useful in your case.

Comment: Forget JSlink and whatever solutions programmers tend to provide. The answer by Naveen using an extra Calculated Column, is clean, simple and 100% the SharePoint way of doing things

Answer (score 0):

Another way using only the UI can be this.

First create a calculated column with formula as

```
=TEXT(Modified,"h")
```

This would return `8` if the item is modified between (inclusive of endpoints) 8:00am to 8:59am. You can now use this column to filter.

Create a new view and use the same formula for `Modified` as you shown in screenshot in your question. Select the `And` radio button and create a new filter column selecting the calculated column with `is equal to` set to `8`.

Save the view and it should show you all the documents modified today between (inclusive of endpoints) 8:00am to 8:59am. But it will *not* show you document modified at 9:00am. For that you will have to write a bit more logic. But this should get you started.